# How to secure nexus repository path

Tags: repository, nexus, nexus3

I have setup a local nexus server with a hosted repo `dev-repo`
`http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/dev-repo/`

In gradle I can download the artifacts hosted like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/dev-repo/"
        credentials {
            username "admin"
            password "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

When I am not logged in, I am able to access the above repository in the browser.
Why is that?
Isn't it secured by Nexus admin account by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Nexus Repository Manager has anonymous access to its components on.  From your URL, I am guessing you are using NXRM2.  This is not well documented in NXRM2, but is hinted at here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Introduction+to+the+User+Interface

You can adjust this in NXRM2 by logging in as admin (or anyone with security permissions) and accessing Administration - Server and the "Anonymous Access" section.

This is discussed [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Anonymous+Access) in NXRM3 documentation, FYI or in case I misanalyzed what version you're on (but the concept is the same).